Hall Effect Thruster electric field explain
I am trying to understand how a hall thruster work.
My understanding is that, first the cathode emits electrons. The electrons get trapped by the magnetic field (Br) and start swirling around at high velocity due to Hall effect. Electric field (Ex) is formed between the anode and the cathode. Noble gas (Xenon/Krypton) is released at the anode and gets ionized by the electron bombardment within the magnetic field region. The positive ion gets accelerated by the electric field and that's how the thrust is created.
My question is, why is the electric field a straight line and not curved into the cathode? Isn't electric field supposed to go from anode to cathode?

